# D3.js heatmap with color

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

Hi I am trying to add in a color scale for my heat map. I Specifically want to use d3.schemeRdYlBu this color scheme but I am having a hard time implementing it. At the moment it just does black. I also have a hover feature with this so I would like that to still work but i am more concerned with just getting the color to work. Obviously having the lower numbers be blue and the higher numbers be red to indicate temp

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<!-- Load d3.js -->
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>

<!-- Create a div where the graph will take place -->
<div id="my_dataviz"></div>

<!-- Load color palettes -->
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-scale-chromatic.v1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-color.v1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-interpolate.v1.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
<script>



// set the dimensions and margins of the graph
var margin = {top: 80, right: 25, bottom: 30, left: 40},
  width = 1000 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 1000 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// append the svg object to the body of the page
var svg = d3.select("#my_dataviz")
.append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
.append("g")
  .attr("transform",
        "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

//Read the data
d3.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Nataliemcg18/Data/master/NASA_Surface_Temperature.csv", function(data) {

  // Labels of row and columns -> unique identifier of the column called 'group' and 'variable'
  var myGroups = d3.map(data, function(d){return d.group;}).keys()
  var myVars = d3.map(data, function(d){return d.variable;}).keys()

  // Build X scales and axis:
  var x = d3.scaleBand()
    .range([ 0, width ])
    .domain(myGroups)
    .padding(0.05);
  svg.append("g")
    .style("font-size", 15)
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x).tickSize(0))
    .select(".domain").remove()

  // Build Y scales and axis:
  var y = d3.scaleBand()
    .range([ height, 0 ])
    .domain(myVars)
    .padding(0.05);
  svg.append("g")
    .style("font-size", 15)
    .call(d3.axisLeft(y).tickSize(0))
    .select(".domain").remove()

  // Build color scale
  var myColor = (d3.schemeRdYlBu[2])



  // create a tooltip
  var tooltip = d3.select("#my_dataviz")
    .append("div")
    .style("opacity", 0)
    .attr("class", "tooltip")
    .style("background-color", "white")
    .style("border", "solid")
    .style("border-width", "2px")
    .style("border-radius", "5px")
    .style("padding", "5px")

  // Three function that change the tooltip when user hover / move / leave a cell
  var mouseover = function(d) {
    tooltip
      .style("opacity", 1)
    d3.select(this)
      .style("stroke", "green")
      .style("opacity", 1)
  }
  var mousemove = function(d) {
    tooltip
      .html("The exact value of this cell is: " + d.value,   )
      .style("left", (d3.mouse(this)[0]+70) + "px")
      .style("top", (d3.mouse(this)[1]) + "px")
  }
  var mouseleave = function(d) {
    tooltip
      .style("opacity", 0)
    d3.select(this)
      .style("stroke", "none")
      .style("opacity", 0.8)
  }

  // add the squares
  svg.selectAll()
    .data(data, function(d) {return d.group+':'+d.variable;})
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.group) })
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.variable) })
      .attr("rx", 4)
      .attr("ry", 4)
      .attr("width", x.bandwidth() )
      .attr("height", y.bandwidth() )
      .style("fill", function(d) { return myColor(d.value)} )
      .style("stroke-width", 4)
      .style("stroke", "none")
      .style("opacity", 0.8)
    .on("mouseover", mouseover)
    .on("mousemove", mousemove)
    .on("mouseleave", mouseleave)
})

// Add title to graph
svg.append("text")
        .attr("x", 0)
        .attr("y", -50)
        .attr("text-anchor", "left")
        .style("font-size", "22px")
        .text("A d3.js heatmap");

// Add subtitle to graph
svg.append("text")
        .attr("x", 0)
        .attr("y", -20)
        .attr("text-anchor", "left")
        .style("font-size", "14px")
        .style("fill", "grey")
        .style("max-width", 400)
        .text("A short description of the take-away message of this chart.");


</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) instead of the regular function to use your own binding of `this` for accessing `myColor` variable.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8" />

<!-- Load d3.js -->
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>

<!-- Create a div where the graph will take place -->
<div id="my_dataviz"></div>

<!-- Load color palettes -->
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-scale-chromatic.v1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-color.v1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-interpolate.v1.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
<script>
  // set the dimensions and margins of the graph
  var margin = { top: 80, right: 25, bottom: 30, left: 40 },
    width = 1000 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 1000 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

  // append the svg object to the body of the page
  var svg = d3
    .select("#my_dataviz")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

  //Read the data
  d3.csv(
    "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Nataliemcg18/Data/master/NASA_Surface_Temperature.csv",
    function (data) {
      // Labels of row and columns -> unique identifier of the column called 'group' and 'variable'
      var myGroups = d3
        .map(data, function (d) {
          return d.group;
        })
        .keys();
      var myVars = d3
        .map(data, function (d) {
          return d.variable;
        })
        .keys();

      // Build X scales and axis:
      var x = d3.scaleBand().range([0, width]).domain(myGroups).padding(0.05);
      svg
        .append("g")
        .style("font-size", 15)
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(d3.axisBottom(x).tickSize(0))
        .select(".domain")
        .remove();

      // Build Y scales and axis:
      var y = d3.scaleBand().range([height, 0]).domain(myVars).padding(0.05);
      svg
        .append("g")
        .style("font-size", 15)
        .call(d3.axisLeft(y).tickSize(0))
        .select(".domain")
        .remove();

      // Build color scale
      var myColor = d3.schemeRdYlBu[3][2];

      // create a tooltip
      var tooltip = d3
        .select("#my_dataviz")
        .append("div")
        .style("opacity", 0)
        .attr("class", "tooltip")
        .style("background-color", "white")
        .style("border", "solid")
        .style("border-width", "2px")
        .style("border-radius", "5px")
        .style("padding", "5px");

      // Three function that change the tooltip when user hover / move / leave a cell
      var mouseover = function (d) {
        tooltip.style("opacity", 1);
        d3.select(this).style("stroke", "green").style("opacity", 1);
      };
      var mousemove = function (d) {
        tooltip
          .html("The exact value of this cell is: " + d.value)
          .style("left", d3.mouse(this)[0] + 70 + "px")
          .style("top", d3.mouse(this)[1] + "px");
      };
      var mouseleave = function (d) {
        tooltip.style("opacity", 0);
        d3.select(this).style("stroke", "none").style("opacity", 0.8);
      };

      // add the squares
      svg
        .selectAll()
        .data(data, function (d) {
          return d.group + ":" + d.variable;
        })
        .enter()
        .append("rect")
        .attr("x", function (d) {
          return x(d.group);
        })
        .attr("y", function (d) {
          return y(d.variable);
        })
        .attr("rx", 4)
        .attr("ry", 4)
        .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
        .attr("height", y.bandwidth())
        .style("fill", (d) => {
          return myColor;
        })
        .style("stroke-width", 4)
        .style("stroke", "none")
        .style("opacity", 0.8)
        .on("mouseover", mouseover)
        .on("mousemove", mousemove)
        .on("mouseleave", mouseleave);
    }
  );

  // Add title to graph
  svg
    .append("text")
    .attr("x", 0)
    .attr("y", -50)
    .attr("text-anchor", "left")
    .style("font-size", "22px")
    .text("A d3.js heatmap");

  // Add subtitle to graph
  svg
    .append("text")
    .attr("x", 0)
    .attr("y", -20)
    .attr("text-anchor", "left")
    .style("font-size", "14px")
    .style("fill", "grey")
    .style("max-width", 400)
    .text("A short description of the take-away message of this chart.");
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, so I tried this and it didnt really seem to work. Can you explain it a bit more       .style("fill", d3.schemeRdYlBu(d) => {
  return myColor(d.value);
})

Comment: The example above for accessing the `myColor` variable but it seems you have another problem, you trying to get a value from `d3.schemeRdYlBu` collections of colors. Why you trying to use `myColor` as a function!? Also, the first collection indexed as **3** that's means `myColor` is `undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

This is another way to get the desired results

```
    var myColor = d3.scaleSequential()
    .interpolator( d3.interpolateRdYlBu)
    .domain([1.37, -.81])
```